# How to make Ubuntu ask for password when mounting partitions?

Tags: mount, policykit

I have been through this kind of feature in older versions of Ubuntu. When I'd like to mount a partition it will ask me a password. Now I want to enable that kind of feature in Ubuntu 12.04.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> According to the **Ubuntu ManPage Repository**, [**pklocalauthority**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pklocalauthority.8.html) - PolicyKit Local Authority makes a distinction between user authentication (to make the user in front of the system prove he really is the user) and administrator authentication (to make the user in front of the system prove he really is an administrator)

Therefore you can use this **policykit** to provide administration authentication for mounting **all** (internal and external) devices.

To do so, follow these steps:

1. Open a terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

   ```
   gksu gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
   ```
2. In line 4, look for **`ResultActive=yes`** and change it to:

   ```
   ResultActive=auth_admin_keep
   ```
3. **Save** and **Close** the file.

Ubuntu will now require a password when mounting **all drives** (internal and external drives).

---

**For specific partitions:**

In 10.04 and newer versions, mounting all devices (internal and external) are allowed without asking for password unless it was defined in the filesystem table (`fstab`) file.

Therefore, to make Ubuntu prompt users for `sudo` password when mounting specific partitions, you need to edit your `fstab` file.

To do so, follow these steps:

1. Open a terminal and type:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/fstab
   ```
2. At the last line, add the **UUID** of your partition with the **defaults** option.

   You can find out the UUIDs of partitions by running `blkid` in the terminal.

   For example:

   ```
   $ sudo blkid
   /dev/sda1: UUID="5474ce02-5c07-4002-a0e7-10c8bc5dba2c" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sda2: LABEL="windows" UUID="7355DDFB0563F31F" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda5: LABEL="data" UUID="7e3fbc57-03fe-4742-bb72-756f31852059" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sda6: LABEL="films" UUID="a319fb28-3061-404f-abbc-6519cf81c6c9" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sda7: LABEL="tv" UUID="5D10E5D66886BCCF" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda8: UUID="12d16683-5530-454e-809b-1a30ed47a8c9" TYPE="swap"
   ```

   Now that you know the UUID, you can add it to the `fstab` file. But first, you need to create a **mountpoint** where the partition will be mounted.

   You can do that by running:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /path/to/dir/name-dir
   ```

   In my example, I want to mount the partition under /media/data:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/data
   ```

   Now, I can simply add the line below to make sure that Ubuntu prompts for a password when the "**data**" partition is mounted:

   ```
   UUID=7e3fbc57-03fe-4742-bb72-756f31852059 /media/data   ext4 defaults 0 0
   ```
3. **Save** and **Close** the file.

**Note:**

The **defaults** option uses the default options that are **rw**, **suid**, **dev**, **exec**, **auto**, **nouser**, and **async**.

The **user** allows normal users to mount the device, whereas **nouser** lets only the root to mount the device.

For detailed information, visit [How to edit and understand /etc/fstab](https://web.archive.org/web/20130504144209/http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html).

Comment: thank you . I'll try that and let you know.is your answer allow me to set password for specific partition ?

Comment: For specific partitions, you need to edit the file system table (`fstab`) file and add that specific partition with `defaults` option which implicitly implements the `nouser` option which lets only the root to mount the device. Will edit my answer to add this info.

Comment: Is there anyway to do the latter option without the partitions being mounted during boot? I know that is what `/etc/fstab` is for...

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is to edit the policy file with one of the commands below:

```
gksu gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

or

```
sudo -H gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

And add `#` at the start of line 2

```
Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
```

changing it to

```
#Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
```

Since the system will no longer identify mount requests as admin or sudo requests it will require the password for mount requests not listed as user mountable in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @muru Thanks for the edit. Do you really think it's necessary to specifically set the HOME environment variable in this case? If so would you be so kind as to share why?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/270019/158442

Answer (score 0):

To ask **password** when you also mount **USB drives** (above answer by @Peachy works only for *internal drives*),

1. Open Terminal (*Shortcut =* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Type

   ```
   sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
   ```
3. Add `org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-*;` to **Line 3**.
4. Change **line 4**, `ResultActive=yes` to `ResultActive=auth_admin`.
5. After edits Lines **1 -4** will look like :

   ```
   [Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]
   Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
   Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-*;
   ResultActive=auth_admin
   ```
6. Save and **Close** file.

Now Ubuntu will ask **password** each time before **mounting usb-drives**.

This worked for me in **Ubuntu 20.04**.