# Making Windows files inaccessible from Ubuntu

Tags: windows, files, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Ubuntu ask for password when mounting partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211623/how-to-make-ubuntu-ask-for-password-when-mounting-partitions)

I've installed Ubuntu on a PC with Windows 7. Now since I want to make that PC a VPN server under Ubuntu I've made the login require no password (Windows still has a password). This makes it easy for anyone to see my Windows files. Can I make them inaccessible (and not visible) from Ubuntu. Sort of like making Ubuntu and Windows two separate systems with their own files on the same hard drive. Thank you! :)

Comment: I am sure that gonna help you, you lock that specific windows drive and nobody else can get to see those partitions except you.

Answer (score 0):

I would mount them with `umask=0077` so only root can read/write them. Then they also stop showing up on the launcher for other users.

The Windows partition will always be visible to someone with root privileges, so this is as close to having them as separate systems as you'll be able to get.

For instance, I have the following line in my `/etc/fstab` to protect my Recovery partition:

```
/dev/sda8 /mnt/Restore ntfs defaults,ro,umask=0077 0 0
```