Do Ext4 file systems not automatically mount?
I'm trying to use 24.10 Oracular Orial and I have an external USB hard drive which I have tried partitioning as MBR, and I also later tried as GPT. Both cases, I created just 1 partition with fdisk. In the case of MBR, I made the partition primary. I did this through terminal by running lsblk. This shows me that /dev/sdb is the disk I'll be targeting.
sudo umount /dev/sdb
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

I started by either creating a gpt, or an MBR table by either typing g, and pressing enter, or typing o, and pressing enter.
Then I made a new partition by pressing n, and then enter, and accepting all default values. (I want the partition to extend to the entire capassity of the disk, all 2TB.)
Then I wrote the changes by typing w, and pressing enter.
Back at my prompt, I then am running
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb

Once done, I close the terminal, then unplug the drive from USB, then plug it back in after about 20 seconds. Here's where the issue then starts. The drive is not mounted to the desktop, nor is it mounted under /media/chris as it should  be like any other drive I've plugged in.
This isn't happening if I use mkfs.exfat. It only seems to happen with mkfs.ext4. Ext4 is the only time it won't automount.
I looked with journalctl -u udisks2 /dev/sdb, everything looks fine. dmesg isn't showing anything out of the ordenary either, aside just that the drive isn't being attempted to mount.
If I manually run
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb

That works even if the file system is Ext4. But, as soon as I either reboot, or unplug the drive, then plug it back in, it again no longer automounts.
After unplugging, then replugging it in, I can confirm that lsblk absolutely shows the drive correctly with the correct file system, partition layout etcetera.
Also, fdisk -l is showing the disk correctly. It's simply just not mounting on its own.
Once manually mounted with udisksctl, I ran ls -ld /media/chris/Storage (Storage is what I labeled the file system), and it looks like the permissions and ownership of the drive are all correct as well as the actual virtual mountpoint.
When I look in /etc/fstab, I see no entries for /dev/sdb of any sort, but I guess that kinda makes sense, as I don't think Ubuntu adds entries automatically to that file when hotplugging external storage media, does it?
I tried adding udisks_allow_external_ext4=true below the last line of /etc/udisks2/udisks2.conf, then restarting the service
sudo systemctl restart udisks2

Which didn't give me any error or any output when I did so, so I assume it worked. However, even then, after unplugging and replugging in the drive, no good.
I'm just totally at a loss. This is absolutely bonkers crazy! You'd think, if exfat was automounting, then there's absolutely no reason why ext4 wouldn't.
What in the world am I missing! I've been at this all day trying to figure this out, and am no closer to finding an answer than when I started.

Sdb is not the first partition, it's sdb1. You wiped out the partition table when you made a filesystem on sdb.

OK, so, should I have done fdisk /dev/sdb1 instead of sdb? Or was I OK there. But when I format, I want to do sdb1? Please can you clarify? I appreciate your time and contribution back to the community.

if this is gnome desktop please check with gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount if it is enabled.

This can be due to policy restriction from Ubuntu, it prevent the automatic mounting of external drives like ext4 by default for security reason.
Lets allow it in `olkit
first open in your favorite editor /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-mount-ext4.pkla
and put this inside:
[Allow user chris to mount ext4 filesystems on external drives]
Identity=unix-user:chris
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes

save and restart Polkit with sudo systemctl restart polkit or simply reboot, then unplug and replug your USB drive and it should work.

That didn't work. I'm being told the file doesn't exist, and it won't even let me save it with pluma for some weird reason. Could this be something where I don't have the polkit package installed? I wouldn't think this matters, but I'm using the Mate desktop environment, and again, this is 24.10.

The issue might be that you format everything with sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb, you should try format just the partition you created, not the entire disk, so lets try to format /dev/sdb1, not /dev/sdb. It will be sudo mkfs.ext4 -L Storage /dev/sdb1 then tell me if it work :)

No. Same issue. And like I said, the suggestion about using polkit isn't working as the directory where that file needs to gho doesn't exist, and even after creating it, it didn't help.

Starting with Ubuntu 23.10, Ubuntu finally upgraded Polkit from the antique version they were using (which used pkla files) to the current version.  See the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1512843/how-to-make-ubuntu-ask-for-password-when-mounting-partitions-in-24-04-noble/1515311#1515311 for where the rules currently go.

Try this:
Plug in the USB drive
Open a terminal.
Run in it:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall gparted
sudo gparted

From Gparted select the USB drive
Unmount it, if it is mounted.
Create a new GPT partition table
Create a partition in the unpartitioned space, ext4 file system.
Apply the changes
Close Gparted
Close the terminal.
Unmount the drive with umount
Open a terminal
Run in it
sudo umount /dev/sdb1 (if your drive is sdb)

Plug it in and see if it automatically mounts to /media/user/?????
If it still doesn't mount, try the following:
Open a terminal.
Run in it:
sudo nano /etc/fstab

Without touching any of its content, add the line at the end (adapt it to your device and desired mounting location)
  /dev/sdb1   /media/user/MiDisco     auto     noauto,x-systemd.automount     0 2

noauto: It means that it will not attempt to mount at boot, where the disk may not be present.
Save the file. Ctrl + O
Close nano. Ctrl + X
Run in terminal:
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
 sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
 sudo systemctl restart local-fs.target

Close the terminal.
